# Get the `Middle` of a string with certain prefix and postfix?

Tags: f#

The following active pattern doesn't use regular expression for better performance. However, it seems quite procedural style. Is it a better way to write in F#?

```
let (|Middle|_|) prefix postfix (input : string) =
    if input.StartsWith(prefix) && input.EndsWith(postfix)
          && input.Length > prefix.Length + postfix.Length then
        let len = input.Length - prefix.Length - postfix.Length
        Some(input.Substring(prefix.Length, len))
    else None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's fine.
Why do you think it's not functional?
I would change only the last line in order to use string slices:

```
if input.StartsWith(prefix) && input.EndsWith(postfix)
      && input.Length > prefix.Length + postfix.Length then
    Some(input.[prefix.Length .. input.Length - postfix.Length - 1])
else None
```

Anyway I don't think it makes it more functional.

Comment: I thought it may have better pattern matching approach for the if-condition too.

Comment: Yes, you can use match, but if you can solve it with an "if .. then" is just fine. If-then in pure functional languages is also a function.

Comment: Perhaps nitpicky, but `if`/`else` is an _expression_.